# How to use Mask in columns in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

> Is it possible to add mask on a column(int or varhchar data type) in
>   SQL Server 2012?

I have a 'Main_Code' column,I want to save the code like '01' or '0001' instead of '1'.I read about the Dynamic Data Mask,but found that it is only available in SQL Server 2016.

**So,what should I do for this format in SQL Server 2012?
And is it necessary to use 'varchar' for mask or 'int' could also be used?**

Comment: You need to store your code as `VARCHAR()` in this case and use `CHECK` constraint. See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292339/6426692)**.

Comment: Masking has *nothing* to do with adding leading zeroes. Masking *hides* sensitive data based on a patter to prevent eg unauthorized users from reading card numbers

Comment: What you ask is just formatting, best performed on the *client*. 1 is always 1. If you want it to display it as `0001` on a web site, the best place to perform this formatting is the web page or view. In a desktop application, it's the format string of the textbox or the data binding expression

Comment: If you want to format values, do so in the SELECT statement, eg with `FORMAT`. Don't change the data type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**'0001'** is not an Integer, to store such data you need to have VARCHAR as your data type.

**Case 1:** If you can't change the data type of the table from int to varchar, in that case you need to do the formatting in your application only. Let the number be stored in integer and do the required formatting in fronted.

**Note**: If it is all about formatting, you should not change your data type. Let it be int only, you do your formatting on front end or in the select statement.

**Case 2:** If you can change the datatype to VARCHAR, in that case you can use following statement in your insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO [Main_Code] (Id) --Mention other column
VALUES(FORMAT(1,'000#')) --Mention other values
```

If you want this to be a custom Auto-Generated Sequences, please follow the example given [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server)

Comment: so,if I use VARCHAR then how would I add values in it?

Comment: Like this INSERT INTO [YourTable] (Id) SELECT FORMAT(1,'000#')

Comment: Are you looking for autoincriment ID column?

Comment: Changing the data type just for formatting is a very, *very* bad idea. For example, the string `002` comes `after` `001000000` which breaks sorting and range searches

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I  agree with you, Ideally it should not be changed. Int is better option