# how to write a query with constraint of 'phone number has 4 consecutive digits between 0 and 2 inclusive' in sql

Tags: sql-server

So far i tried doing this, but it is wrong

Phone like '[0-2][0-2][0-2][0-2]'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to CREATE TABLE with formatted column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291901/how-to-create-table-with-formatted-column)

Comment: When someone look to the title, you say a query, while in the body it seems like you are looking for a constrint for your column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you check, if the phone number consists only of four digits between 0 and 2. You need to add wildcards if there can be more characters in the phone number.

- If the four digits can appear anywhere in the string use:

  ```
  CHECK (phone LIKE '%[0-2][0-2][0-2][0-2]%')
  ```
- If they can only appear at the beginning use:

  ```
  CHECK (phone LIKE '[0-2][0-2][0-2][0-2]%')
  ```
- If they can only appear at the end use:

  ```
  CHECK (phone LIKE '%[0-2][0-2][0-2][0-2]')
  ```

Comment: yes i did that too, but is giving me wrong answer as it must find phone numbers with four consecutive numbers from 0-2. Example: 5874320000, 4035872222, 2222567890, 1111587234 Something like that

Comment: @denise: Should it reject number with four 0-2 digits or only accept such numbers and reject all the others?

Comment: it should accept phone numbers with 4consecutive numbers from 0-2 inclusive

Comment: @denise: Then my solution works just fine with your numbers: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=82249bf48ce080a9ae6cbcb23de02639

Comment: got it, Thank you! I was missing one character. My bad